# Django admin inline: select all for delete?

Tags: django, django-admin

In django admin inline forms, there are checkboxes for deleting individual inline objects.  Is there a way to enable selecting all of them at once for deletion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution I worked out:

In templates/admin/edit_inline/tabular.html

```
{% if inline_admin_formset.formset.can_delete %}<th>{% trans "Delete?" %}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" class="selectall_checkbox"/></th>{% endif %}
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.selectall_checkbox').click(function(e) {
    $(e.target).closest('table').find(':checkbox').filter(function () { return /DELETE/.test(this.name); }).each(function () {    
      this.checked = e.target.checked;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

And here is a similar solution, but checkbox inserts with jQuery in footer block of admin/base_site.html template:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
...

{% block footer %}
<script type="text/javascript">
var $ = django.jQuery;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tabular table th:contains({% trans "Delete?" %})').each(function(index) {
        var text = $(this).text();
        $(this).html('<input type="checkbox" class="selectall_checkbox">&nbsp; ' + text);
    });
    $('.selectall_checkbox').click(function(e) {
        $(e.target).closest('table').find(':checkbox').filter(function () { return /DELETE/.test(this.name); }).each(function () {    
          this.checked = e.target.checked;
        });
    });
});
</script>
{% endblock footer %}
```